# "Invalid Date" error for date parameter in GET method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am passing a date string as a query parameter in a GET method. The string, when hardcoded and converted using `new Date(date)` method, works fine. However, if I try to do the same with the query parameter, it's throwing "Invalid Date" error.
The format of the date string is ISO8601. My query endpoint is:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/range?startDate=%222018-10-11T12%3A55%3A37.000Z%22
```

The date string is `"2018-10-11T12:55:37.000Z"`

Node snippet:

```
exports.searchItems = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    let startDate = req.swagger.params.startDate.value;
    validCheck = new Date(startDate)
    webUtils.sendResponse(res, 200, validCheck);
  } catch (err) {
    webUtils.errorHandler(res, err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant node.js code please

Comment: @George Updated with snippet. Please correlate

Comment: Have you checked the actual value of `startDate` before using it to create the new Date? Is it the string you are expecting?

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment, it might be that the `%22` at the start and end of the query param may actually be putting the double-quote as part of the string. If so, this would need to be removed to create a valid date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from my question comment, I double checked in node 8 , using the snippet `require('url').parse('/range?startDate=%222018-10-11T12%3A55%3A37.000Z%22', true)` and the query is being parsed with the double-quote as part of the string. I.e. the query part of result object is:

`{..., query: { startDate: '"2018-10-11T12:55:37.000Z"' }, ... }`

The quotes would need to be removed to create a valid date string to use in the `Date` constructor.

Comment: good answer, I would like to add: quotes shouldn't be a part of the request parameter payload. If you control the client who makes the request, ask them to strip it in the request instead of you handling it in the server code.

Comment: Thank you @Code_Frank,@dubes. That moment when you spend half of the day on an issue to find such an elegant solution to it eventually (facepalm)